# Is $f = Sin(X_t)$ a Lipschitz function?

Tags: calculus, stochastic-calculus

Applying the MVT we know there exists a constant $c \in (a,b)$ such that 
$$ f'(c) = \frac{f(b)- f(a)}{b-a},$$
and
$$ f'(X_t) = Cos(X_t)dB_t-\frac{1}{2}Sin(X_t) dt .$$
Hence 
$$ f'(c) = Cos(c)dB_t-\frac{1}{2}Sin(c) dt, $$
and 
$$ |Cos(c)dB_t-\frac{1}{2}Sin(c) dt| = \left|\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}\right|$$

I'm unsure how to show the LHS is bounded by some $k$. My ultimate goal is to show that if

$$|Cos(c)dB_t-\frac{1}{2}Sin(c) dt|\le k$$

then

$$|f(b)-f(a)|\le k|b-a|$$

and we would then be able to deduce it is Lipschitz.

Comment: You're applying a theorem from the calculus of real-valued functions to a stochastic process.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I see.. would there be another way to go about this then?

Comment: I thought I could still use it since we can still differentiate $X_t$. Is MVT strictly for real valued functions then?

Comment: $f'(X_t)$ is meaningless.  Rather, $df_t=\cos(X_t)dX_t-\frac12\sin(X_t)dt$.

Comment: OK thanks, makes sense. I shall try think of another way of doing this and will post it if i can.

Comment: Confusion between functions, their values, and functions composed with random processes, produces its full effects here, unfortunately, which is simply chaos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a stochastic analogue of the mean-value theorem [See this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3215435?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

To summarize, it states that if $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative random variable such that $Pr(X>t)\le Pr(Y>t)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $E[X]<E[Y]<\infty$, and $g$ is a measurable and differentiable function such that $E[g(X)]$ and $E[g(Y)]$ are finite, and $g'$ is measurable and Riemann integrable on $[x,y]$ for all $y\ge x\ge 0$, then there exists a random variable $Z$ such that

$$E[g(X)]-E[g(Y)]=E[g'(Z)]\,(E[X]-E[Y])$$

Comment: Although interesting for sure - I'm not sure how it can be used in this example however.

Comment: Why does it not apply?  Let $g(x)=\sin(x)$. Then, $g'(x)=\cos(x)$ and clearly $-1\le E[\cos(Z)]\le 1$.  Hence, in terms of expectations, $$\left|\,E[\sin(X_t)]-E[\sin(Y_y)]\,\right|\le \left|\,E[X_t]-E[Y_t] \,\right|$$

Comment: Was this answer, supplemented by the comment, useful in helping show that $f$ is Lipschitz?

Comment: Okay yes i see, thank-you!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.